# Problem on threads to calculate prime numbers from start to end

Tags: c, pthreads

```
#include<stdio.h>//-lpthread suppoting library
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<math.h>

int isPrime(int n){
    for(int i=2;i<=sqrt(n);i++){
        if(n%i==0){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

void *child(void *param){
    int n=(int)param;
    return (void*)isPrime(n);
}

int main(){
    int start,end,prime;
    printf("Enter start and end for prime number generation:\n");
    scanf("%d %d",&start,&end);
    pthread_t thread[end-start+1];
    for(int i=start,j=0;i<=end;i++,j++){
        pthread_create(&thread[j],0,&child,(void*)i);
        printf("hi");
        pthread_join(thread[j],(void*)&prime);
        if(prime==1){
            printf("%d\t",i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the C code I have written so far to list prime numbers from start to end from the user.In a for loop it creates a thread to check if a number is prime or not.Lastly it joins and it returns 1 for prime and 0 for not prime.

But however it only goes through the for loop once for some reason.I don't know what the problem is...

Sample input:Enter start and end for prime number generation:
25 35

Output:      hi25

I used hi to check how many times it was looping. I guess only once since it has only one hi.

Expected result: Enter start and end for prime number generation:
25 35

Output:      29 31

Comment: Can't reproduce. When I run the code I get: `hi25    hihihihi29      hihi31  hihihihi`

Comment: BTW, 25 is not a prime number.

Comment: I have just run it again with no changes, I still get the same output.

Comment: ahh yes 25 is not a prime number. Something isn't adding up, 25 was not supposed to  get printed.

Comment: How are we getting different output??? Looks like your for loop is looping, mine isn't for some reason.

Comment: @kaylum how did you run the program? I have fixed the 25 problem too. You probably just ran it different.

Comment: In `pthread_join(thread[j], (void*)&prime)` it expects pointer to pointer but you pass pointer to integer, it smashes stack.

Comment: @dimich thanks so much it works now. But I don’t get it , both are just storing addresses anyway right?Shouldn’t it work the same anyways?Or is it some internal function of join that just needs another pointer to pass. Next time I’ll make sure to to read what a function expects. Thanks anways…

Comment: @RahulDubba when size of pointer is greater than size of integer (e.g. on x86_64 platform) `pthread_join()` writes 8 bytes to 4-byte variable. Actually it's undefined behaviour. I have `warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size` in three places when compile your code and `*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated` when run it.

Comment: Do you have to use threads for this?  I am inclined to think that a single-threaded sieve-based approach would outperform what you've presented or anything much like it.

Comment: What's more, you join each thread before creating the next, thereby throwing away any concurrency advantage you might otherwise have gained.  This is strictly worse than just calling the thread function directly.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I’m still a student who’s learning thread. As you can see from the above answer it was solved with a thread which was definitely not needed. And the worse part was that I made an error with pointers. There’s still a lot for me to learn about C. Next time  I’ll use threads to my advantage , thanks anyways!!!